# PHP: How to transfer files from IBM (Unix) filesystem to Windows network share?

Tags: php, windows, networking, ibm-midrange

We have a Windows network share of say `\\share\drive`, but if I try to save to that in PHP it just tells me directory not found (though it works from my Windows box).

Our IBM guy says it should work but it doesn't... I've tried various combinations and I have no examples in our PHP code of anything doing this (to any share).

```
$share = '\\\\share\\drive'; // or '//share/drive'
file_put_contents($share, 'blah');
```

IBM docs say it'll just work as UNC... but it doesn't... so at this point I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mount your winDoze network share on the 'nix file system?  Just because winDoze is sharing the directory doesn't mean anybody else knows it's there - you still have to mount the directory for your PHP code to be able to see it.

BTW, this isn't a programming question, so it really doesn't belong here, you should be asking on ServerFault.

---

**EDIT**

Try this:  Open a shell prompt on your IBM system, and run this command:

```
find / -name "<drive>"
```

where `<drive>` is the *share name* of the *Windows network share*.  If `find` finds a location for your network share, you will have the path to use in its output.

If `find` returns an empty result set, run `mount` at the shell prompt.  You will get an output that looks something like this:

```
/dev/vzfs on / type reiserfs (rw,usrquota,grpquota)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
none on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
```

Chances are ***extremely high*** that you won't find your network share `<drive>` in this list, either.  That means you need to **mount the network share** as a resource on your Unix system.  There should be an empty directory (usually `/mnt`) that you can mount the network share on, read the `mount` man page for instructions.

Comment: How is it not a programming question? I have to transfer the files using PHP.

Comment: Agreed, you are trying to transfer the files using PHP, but the problem you are having is not that PHP isn't working, but that your *file system* isn't working, i.e., you don't need to do anything to your *program*, you have to fix the *environment it's working in*.